# Find Out Existence of Built-in TypeScript Declarations Using the NPM CLI

Tags: typescript, npm

On the NPM website it is possible to see for each package
if it provides TypeScript declarations in an @types package (DT icon)
or if it contains built-in TypeScript declarations (TS icon).

Is there a way to find out with which of both kinds of package I'm dealing,
using the NPM CLI, before installing a stub @types package?

Comment: I don't think `npm info <package>` shows it, but `npm --verbose <command>` lets you see what requests it makes - then you can make the same one and check the response. Looks like it's keyed on `types`: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html.